# Scope of private variables within inner classes

Tags: java, scope

Consider the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
        private String barbar;

        public Bar( String b ) { barbar = b; }
    }

    class Meh
    {
        Bar b = new Bar("BAR!");

        public void displayName() {
            System.out.println( b.barbar );
        }    
    }
}
```

Java allows class `Meh` to access the private instance variable, `barbar`, which is declared as `private` within `Bar`.

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103811/scope-of-private-variables-in-an-inner-class). However, the answer just basically reiterates that the observed scope is what it is (that `barbar` is accessible within the braces of class `Foo`), but offers no explanation. After some Googling, I hadn't been able to land on a good discussion of this behavior. What I would like to know is if there's a specific rationale for this scoping behavior. I would have expected `barbar` to be private "within the braces" of class `Bar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental aspect of this is that *[inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)* (as opposed to *static nested classes*) are *part of* their enclosing class. They aren't separate from it, or from each other. So just like other parts of the enclosing class (constructors and methods) have access to all of its private information, so do all the members of the inner classes. Inner classes are, in some sense, a bit of a fiction that we use as a convenient abstraction mechanism. And since inner classes are *part of* the enclosing class, their private information is *its* private information, and so is shared with other inner classes.

Comment: OK, I understand this concept of "part of the outer class". It does, though, seem to at least slightly defy what I would have considered an intuitive notion of scoping. If, for example, in the functional program world, like in Pascal, if I declare a function within a function, the local variables within the inner function are not accessible (and reasonably so) to the outer function. To me, that kind of scoping is almost intuitively obvious. The Java handling of inner classes, as you explained it, took me a little by surprise.

Comment: @lurker: You and me both. :-) Inner classes are a breed unto themselves. They don't follow the [Matryoshka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) scope rules that most things do. It's surprising (to many of us), but that's the decision they made when adding them.

Comment: Well, I'm now happy that I'm no the only one that feels that way. :) So here's a related question: if I made the variable within `Bar` to be public instead of private would it then become accessible outside of `Foo` even though it's from an inner class?

Comment: What annoys me most about this is not the existence of such a “friend” relationship but that there is no possibility to opt out, i.e. no way of declaring “real private” members that shouldn’t be accessed by outer classes nor siblings. However, it’s not exclusive to inner classes, i.e. within the same package, `protected` members are not really protected…

Comment: @lurker: Yes, if `Bar` were public, but the code would have to have a `Bar` reference, not a `Foo` reference. So it would have to call a `Foo` method that returned the `Bar`, since if `Bar` is an inner class, it cannot be constructed without an enclosing `Foo`. [Example.](http://ideone.com/zWK7AQ)

Comment: The implementation that Java uses for `private` seems to make a class a bit less "portable" in the sense that if I have an inner class and am accessing some of its `private` variables directly elsewhere in the outer class, the code breaks if I decide to hoist the inner class out and make it separate from the outer class. So getters would need to be added, or the variables made `public` in the process of such a change. Of course, there are probably some bad code smells in that scenario...

Comment: @lurker: *My* take-away from all this is: Use inner classes *very sparingly, if at all*. I've had virtually no need of them (not having done any Spring development, where anonymous inner classes -- blech -- are de rigour for event handlers).

Comment: I think that makes sense, in general. I hit this because recently I had what seemed an ideal use for them. I was really almost using them as a few small, private data structures within the outer class where they were very application-specific to the outer class they were contained in.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

> The body of a class declares members (fields and methods and **nested
>   classes** and interfaces), instance and static initializers, and
>   constructors. The **scope of a member is the
>   entire body of the declaration of the class to which the member
>   belongs.** Field, method, member class, member interface, and
>   constructor declarations may include the access modifiers
>   public, protected, or private.

So, as per the example, class `Bar` and class `Meh` both belongs class `Foo`.

Hence, any member of Foo will have access to all its other members regardless its a field method or nested class/interface as per the first line in the specs.

---

Comment questioin:

> If I made the variable within `Bar` to be `public` instead of private would it then become accessible outside of Foo even though it's from an inner class?

Yes of course it is accessible from outside of the class. 
Look at the below example

```
class A {

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo.Bar bar = foo.new Bar("name");

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        bar.barbar = "someOtherName"; 
        //this is valid only if barbar is public
        //or if it is default and within the same package
    }

}
```

Comment: If I made the variable within `Bar` to be `public` instead of `private` would it then become accessible outside of `Foo` even though it's from an inner class?

Comment: @lurker yes, it is accessible, only if it is public or no modifier(within package). I have explained taking example classA.

Comment: Thank you. So that means at least there's *some* value in use of the `private` keyword on an instance variable in an inner class. BTW, thank you for the corrective edit on my question!

Comment: lol, if not, then there wouldn't be any meaning for privacy (`private`) :P

Comment: Well of course there is a more predictable meaning of `private` in other contexts in Java. This particular one was throwing me for a loop since it is really sort of `semi-private` or `outer-class-private`. I just needed to confirm what `private` actually meant in this case!

Answer (score 1):

The inner class is just a way to cleanly separate some functionality that really belongs to the original outer class. They are intended to be used when you have 2 requirements:

Some piece of functionality in your outer class would be most clear if it was implemented in a separate class.
Even though it's in a separate class, the functionality is very closely tied to way that the outer class works.
Given these requirements, inner classes have full access to their outer class. Since they're basically a member of the outer class, it makes sense that they have access to methods and attributes of the outer class -- including privates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to find the rationale behind the design of the language unless you talk to the people who designed it.  However, one can often get insight into the "why" through the Java Language Specification.  [Section 6.3 (Scope of a Declaration)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) lays out the rules for scoping and has examples of the rules in action.

Specifically, the behavior you're asking about is covered by the statement:

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block
>   is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own
>   class declaration.

Your two local classes have the same scope, i.e. the "immediately enclosing block", specifically class `Foo`.

Perhaps in your question you can explain why you think `barbar` should be inaccessible to the enclosing class, and then we can address any misconceptions you have about how Java works.

Comment: My reason for thinking `barbar` should only be accessible within `Bar` is because that's what I would consider to be the typical behavior of `private` within a class in my other OOP experiences.

Comment: I think the case in your question is covered by this statement: "The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration."  Your two local classes have the same scope, i.e. the "immediately enclosing block", specifically class `Foo`.